# Proper table design for sparse primary key

Tags: sql-server, database-design

In my system I have temporary entities that are created based on rules stored in my database, and the entities are not persisted.

Now, I need is to store information about these entities, and because they are created based on rules and are not stored, they have no ID.

I came up with a formula to generate an ID for these temp entities based on the rule that was used to generate them: id = rule id + "-" + entity index in the rule. This formula generates unique strings of the form 164-3, 123-0, 432-2, etc...

My question is how should I build my table (regarding primary key and clustered index) when my keys have no relation or order? Keep in mind that I will only (99.9% of the time) query the table using the id mentioned above.

Options I thought about after much reading, but don't have the knowledge to determine which is better:

1) primary key on a varchar column with clustered index. -According to various sources, this would be bad because of fragmentation and the wideness of the key. Also their format is pretty weird for sorting.

2) primary key on varchar column without clustered index (heap table). -Also a bad idea according to various sources due to indexing and fragmentation issues.

3) identity int column with clustered index, and a varchar column as primary key with unique index. -Can't really see the benefit of the surogate key here since it would mainly help with range queries and ordering and I would never query the table based on this key because it would be unknown at all times.

4) 2 columns composite key: rule id + rule index columns.
-Now I don't have strings but I have two columns that will be copied to FKs and non clustered indexes. Also I'm not sure what indexes I would use in this case.

Can anybody shine a light here? Any help is appreciated.

--Edit
I will perform more selects than inserts;
I will perform more inserts than updates;
All selects will include at least rule id;

If I use a surogate primary key, and a unique index on (rule id, index), then I can use the surogate for subsequent operations after retrieving data by rule id, which would be faster. Also, inserts would be faster.
However, because the data will be stored according to the surogate key, I might have records that have the same rule id, but different index, stored quite far from each other on disk, which means even with an index on rule id, retrieving the data could be kinda slow.

If I use (rule id, index) as clustered primary key, rows with same rule id would be stored close to each other, and selecting data by rule id would be efficient enough. However, I suspect inserts would be slow.

Is the rationale above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a heap is generally a bad idea unless proven otherwise. Even so, you will need a very solid reason for not having a clustered index (any one will make things better, even on `identity` column).

Storing this key in a single column is okay; if you want natural sorting, you can pad your numbers with zeroes, for example. However, this will widen the key.

Having a composite primary key (and, subsequently, foreign keys) is completely acceptable, especially when dealing with natural keys, like the one you have. This will give you the narrowest possible key - `int` + `int` or some such - while eliminating the sorting issue at the same time. I would recommend to make this PK clustered to reduce additional key lookups.

Fragmentation here will not be a big issue; at least, no bigger than with any other indexing decision. Any index built on such a key will be prone to fragmentation, clustered or no. In any case, your DBA should know how to keep an index such as this in top form.

Regarding the order of columns in the index, the following rules usually apply:

1. If partial key match will take place (filtering by one part of the key but not by the other) the one which is used most often should go first;
2. If No.1 isn't applicable and all parts of the key used in all queries, the column with the highest [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)) should go first.

The order of remaining columns (if there are more than 1) isn't of much importance because SQL Server only creates distribution statistics for the first column in a composite index. However, it is a good idea to list them in order of decreasing cardinality.

**EDIT:** Seeing your update with additional details, here are the most suitable options. Suppose your table looks like this:

```
-- Sample table
create table dbo.TempEntities (
    RuleId int not null,
    IndexId int not null,
    -- Remaining columns listed here
    EntityData xml not null
);
go
```

From here, the most straightforward way is to use the natural key as a clustered index:

```
-- Option 1 - natural clustered index
alter table dbo.TempEntities
add constraint PK_TempEntities primary key clustered (RuleId, IndexId);
go
```

However, if you have any child tables that would reference this one, it might not be the most convenient solution, because natural keys are prone to updates, which creates a mess where you could avoid it. Instead, a surrogate key can be introduced, like this:

```
-- Option 2 - surrogate clustered, natural nonclustered
alter table dbo.TempEntities add Id bigint identity(1,1) not null;

alter table dbo.TempEntities
add constraint PK_TempEntities primary key clustered (Id);

alter table dbo.TempEntities
add constraint UQ_TempEntities_RuleIdIndexId unique (RuleId, IndexId);
go
```

It makes sense to have the surrogate PK clustered, because it will result in much less page splits, making inserts faster (despite having one index more compared to Option 1). Without any intimate knowledge of your queries, this is probably the most balanced solution.

Shuffling the `clustered` attribute between surrogate and natural keys has mostly academic value and can only make difference on a high-load system with hundreds of inserts happening every second on 24*7 schedule. If your system is indeed as such, please seek a professional consultant who will analyse your queries and provide the solution tailored to your situation.

Comment: Thanks. What is the best order (rule id, index) or (index, rule id)? And how would my index on that look like?

Comment: @victor, updated my answer. Not sure about "look like" - you mean, the actual `alter table ... add constraint ...` statement?

Comment: I meant clustered, non clustered, order of columns, etc... After much reading I think the best is to go with clustered primary key (rule id, index) because I will ofter query only by rule id, which will use the index. You think if had a surogate int clustered pkey, plus a unique index on (rule,index) the queries would be more performant, since after I query by rule id, I could use the surogate id for subsequent operations?

Comment: I edited my question and added more information regarding the queries. I also added two designs I came up with after reading your answer. Ca you comment on them?

Comment: Yeah. After hundreds of pages, I came to the same conclusion: the surogate helps inserts; index on (rule id, index id) helps when filtering by those values; and an indexed varchar(20) for "ruleid-indexid" for when I need a WHERE_IN, .e.g. where X in (Y), which can't be satisfactorily done using multiple columns. I think the string won't be so bad, since they represent a well defined sequence of integers, plus a dash. They can be sorted, it is just more expensive; also, they are unique, which is great for indexes.

Comment: I could get awy with just int ID and the string "rule-index", but also having separate columns for rule and index helps when I need to select all from a specific rule, or when I only need a specific index of a rule. These extra columns would outperform the string column since they are integers. Not sure if that makes a lot of sense, but my querying scenarios vary quite a bit.

Comment: If you need a string representation of your composite key, you can either add a computed column, or create a view on this table with such a column provided. The view can also be indexed, though it might entangle you too much in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, I could use a  view or a computed column. The view just feels like overkill here; and the computed column feels right but the database would have to perform casts and concatenation quite often, and I always have this information upon isertion, so I guess I'll just save the db some work and use a bit more space (approx +10mb every 1 million rows). **I might be wrong about saving computation time, since I dont know how computed columns are indexed, but Im guessing this would be a persisted computed column**.

Comment: Yes, in order to be indexed, it has to be persisted. And this little extra space goes a long way in terms of performance.